# Non-Linear/Linear Programming in python

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I have optimization that goes like this :

```
Maximize (x1*a1 + x2*a2+...+xn * an) 

such that :
  any j,  (xj*aj)/sum(all xi*ai) <= 0.35 
  any two j, (xj*aj)/sum(all xi*ai) >= 0.15
  any three j, (xj*aj)/sum(all xi*ai) >= 0.07 
  any j  1<= aj <= 100 and aj is an integer.
```

I have tried to implement the same using Scipy.optimize. However, I am not sure if the method being used is right as SLSQP gives doesnt solve it for any input.
I have tried using both Scipy and pulp for solving the same with different constraint formulations. However, neither seems to work. I have shared the scipy code below. I am not sure if scipy/pulp allows ifelse constraints or take constraints in a loop.

```
share = 
[1595798.061003,1595798.061003,1595798.061003,1595798.061003,
6335021.83000001,6335021.83000001,6335021.83000001,
6335021.83000001,42842994.4958]

def objective(factors):
    mult = []
    for i in range(len(share)):
       mult.append(share[i]*factors[i])

return -sum(mult)

def constraint1(factors):
    #n=len(factors)
    sum_w = 0
    for i in range(len(share)):
       sum_w= sum_w+(share[i]*factors[i])
    sum_f =0 
    for j in range(len(share)):
        print((share[j]*factors[j])/sum_w)
        if(((share[j]*factors[j])/sum_w) -0.35) <= 0 :
            sum_f = sum_f + 0
        else:
            sum_f = sum_f + 1
return sum_f 

def constraint2(factors):
    sum_w = 0
    for i in range(len(share)):
        sum_w= sum_w+(share[i]*factors[i])
    sum_f2 =0 
    for j in range(len(share)):
        if(((share[j]*factors[j])*100/sum_w) - 0.15) >= 0 :
            sum_f2 = sum_f2 + 1
        else:
            sum_f2 = sum_f2 + 0
return sum_f2 - 2

def constraint3(factors):
    sum_w = 0
    for i in range(len(share)):
        sum_w= sum_w+(share[i]*factors[i])
    sum_f3 =0 
    for j in range(len(share)):
       if(((share[j]*factors[j])*100/sum_w) - 0.07) >= 0 :
           sum_f3 = sum_f3 + 1
       else:
           sum_f3 = sum_f3 + 0
return sum_f3 - 3 

bounds = []
share0=[]

for i in range(len(share)):
    bounds.append((1,100))
    share0.append(100)

cons1={'type': 'eq','fun' : constraint1}
cons2={'type': 'ineq','fun' : constraint2}
cons3={'type': 'ineq','fun' : constraint3} 

cons=[cons1]
sol=minimize(objective,share0,method='SLSQP',bounds=bounds,constraints=cons)
```

The output i get shows :

```
fun: 7387762651.568393
jac: array([ -1595776.,  -1595776.,  -1595776.,  -1595776.,  -6335040.,
    -6335040.,  -6335040.,  -6335040., -42843008.])
message: 'Singular matrix C in LSQ subproblem'
nfev: 11
nit: 1
njev: 1
status: 6
success: False
x: array([ 100. , 100. , 100. , 100. , 100., 100., 100., 100., 100. ])
```

What method should i be using here?

Comment: I don't think SLSQP is very suited for this kind of problem. It assumes smooth, differentiable functions. 

I think this problem can be modeled as a linear MIP problem (after some non-trivial linearizations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PySCIPOpt](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt) should be fine handling those constraints. It's more reliable than SciPy, especially considering that you are dealing with integer variables and some nonlinearities that you can directly model like you suggested.